# Retrieve multiple images from document directory

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, nsdocumentdirectory

I have folder named "2" in document directory. Now in folder "2", I have five images named 0.png, 1.png, 2.png, 3.png and 4.png. I want to retrieve these images and save into an array. I have code but it returns only one image.

```
int b=2;
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,     NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSLog(@"%@",paths);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *getImagePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d/0.png",b]];
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:getImagePath];
NSLog(@"%@",getImagePath);
imge.image=img;
```

Comment: By the way, one should generally be wary about loading arrays full of images because images often consume a lot of memory. If you've only got a few, or if you have a compelling business case to load them in an array, that's fine. But nine times out of ten, it's better to load an array of image names, and have the UI load the images as it needs them, not loading all of them ahead of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use NSFileManager, something like this:

```
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:path error:&error];
```

It will give you an array with all the file paths for all files in the given path.

---

This is how you load the images from the array of URLs.

```
NSArray *paths = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:path error:&error];
for (NSURL *url in paths)
{
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url]];
}
```

Comment: This way, the value in array will be (0,1,2,3,4). We still need to create URLs and then get images from them.

Comment: You do not need to create URLs. This method already returns URLs of the files contained in the folder. So you then just need to load the image. I've update the answer with code how to load the images.

Answer (score 1):

You should loop through the images.

```
int b=2;
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,     NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSLog(@"%@",paths);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

NSMutableArray *images = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:5];

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
   NSString *getImagePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString     stringWithFormat:@"%d/%d.png",b, i]];
   UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:getImagePath];
   [images addObject:img];
   NSLog(@"%@",getImagePath);
   imge.image=img;
}
```

Instead of hardcoding the count and names of the image files, as Dominik suggested you should use contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:error: to get the list of files in that directory.

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *imageFileNames = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:[documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",b]] error:&error];
```

Comment: Downside of this is that you have to hard code the number of the images in the directory, but if he will use the `contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:error:` method of `NSFileManager` he can get both paths of the files and also the count.