# Creating UICollectionView programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewdelegate

I am learning how to create a UICollectionView programmatically. I want to create a grid of pictures collected from the user in another part of the app.
Will this sample code help me accomplish this? Also, how do I configure the data to emit the image I want? My source code is below.

UICollectionView:

```
class PhotosViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let imageStore = ImageStore()
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        let layout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 20, left: 10, bottom: 10, right: 10)
        layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: 100, height: 100)

        let myCollectionView:UICollectionView = UICollectionView(frame: self.view.frame, collectionViewLayout: layout)
        myCollectionView.dataSource = self
        myCollectionView.delegate = self
        myCollectionView.registerClass(RDCellCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "MyCell")
        myCollectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        self.view.addSubview(myCollectionView)
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return images.count
    }

    var images: [UIImage] = [

    ]

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let myCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("MyCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! RDCellCollectionViewCell
        myCell.imageView.image = images[indexPath.item]
        myCell.backgroundColor = UIColor.grayColor()
        return myCell
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
    {
        print("User tapped on item \(indexPath.row)")
    }
}
```

ImageStore.swift:

```
class ImageStore: NSObject {

    let cache = NSCache()

    func setImage(image: UIImage, forKey key: String) {
        cache.setObject(image, forKey: key)

        let imageURL = imageURLForKey(key)

        if let data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.5) {
            data.writeToURL(imageURL, atomically: true)
        }
    }
    func imageForKey(key: String) -> UIImage? {
        if let existingImage = cache.objectForKey(key) as? UIImage {
            return existingImage
        }

        let imageURL = imageURLForKey(key)
        guard let imageFromDisk = UIImage(contentsOfFile: imageURL.path!) else {
            return nil
        }

        cache.setObject(imageFromDisk, forKey: key)
        return imageFromDisk
    }

    func deleteImageForKey(key: String) {
        cache.removeObjectForKey(key)

        let imageURL = imageURLForKey(key)
        do {
            try NSFileManager.defaultManager().removeItemAtURL(imageURL)
        }
        catch let deleteError {
            print("Error removing the image from disk: \(deleteError)")
        }
    }

    func imageURLForKey(key: String) -> NSURL {
        let documentsDirectories =
        NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask)
        let documentDirectory = documentsDirectories.first!

        return documentDirectory.URLByAppendingPathComponent(key)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track. You'll need to create a subclass of UICollectionViewCell that contains a UIImageView; this will let you plug the correct UIImage into it in cellForItemAtIndexPath.

This describes how to hook up your custom cell:
[Create UICollectionViewCell programmatically without nib or storyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23890131/create-uicollectionviewcell-programmatically-without-nib-or-storyboard)

As for getting the correct image, you'll need to map the index path to your image store somehow, so that an item number corresponds to the correct image key.

Comment: I reviewed the question that you linked. I am new to this, and am still very confused. What am I supposed to put in my subclass? The goal of the application is to create a UICollectionView of pictures that the user uploaded in another part of the app.

Comment: The subclass would contain a UIImageView. Your subclass will add the UIImageView as a subview of its content view, and also you'll need to provide a size for the UIImageView. Then, in cellForRowAtIndexPath, you'll just plug the appropriate UIImage into the cell's UIImageView.

Comment: This tutorial looks pretty good: https://randexdev.com/2014/08/uicollectionviewcell/

Comment: I created the subclass, but I am still unsure how to show the images collected from the user. I added my subclass to the question.

Comment: In viewWillAppear, make sure you register RDCellCollectionViewCell (using the registerClass method of the collection view). Then, in cellForItemAtIndexPath, when you set myCell, add "as! RDCellCollectionViewCell" to the end of the dequeue line; this will make sure that myCell is an instance of your subclass. Then you'll be able to set cell.imageView.image equal to the UIImage you want to show up in the cell.

Comment: I have already done this. But I am not trying to display one single image. I do not know how to display all images collected from the user.

Comment: Oh; your code in the question doesn't reflect your recent work. Anyhow, you want to display one single image in each cell, correct? That is what the code is set up to do: A single image per cell, many cells per collection view.

Comment: Yes, but I do not know what to set cell.imageView.image to.

Comment: In cellForItemAtIndexPath, you are passed indexPath. It has an item number as one of its properties. Each cell in a given section will have a unique item number. A common practice is to load up the data into an array, which is saved as a property of the view controller, and then to pull the data for the cell out of the array, using indexPath.item. So, in cellForItemAtIndexPath, you'd have cell.imageView.image = images[indexPath.item].

Comment: I have no identifier named "images". My image info is stored in ImageStore so that is what I tried, but I got this error. (See bottom of question for error)

Comment: I understand that I need an array, but how should I compose the array?

Comment: This question helped me with the array http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32407249/proper-way-to-iterate-and-load-images-from-array-into-collectionviewcontroller-i but how do I put the collected images into the array?

Comment: If u have few images probably u already have the array. If images come from server u can add them to NSMutableArray in loop or, better stuff, create custom class for data which u got from server and image will be one of class property.

Comment: From what I can see of your code, one way would be to add a method to ImageStore that returns an array of all the saved images. You can use NSFileManager and loop through the saved files.

Comment: (ps Please update the code in your question; it's very difficult to help you when I can't see your current code)

Comment: @user3820674 How do I create a custom class for the data? That is what I want to do.

Comment: @JoshuaKaden That sounds good. How do I do that? Please provide example code. Also, I will update the code.

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17747860/retrieve-multiple-images-from-document-directory

Comment: That answer is in objective-c. @JoshuaKaden

Comment: A quick google search led me to this tutorial, which has some Swift code that reads images from the file system and loads them into an array. http://sweettutos.com/2016/01/31/how-to-programmatically-save-and-load-uiimage-files-in-the-document-directory-with-swift/

Comment: My search terms were: "load uiimage files nsfilemanager swift", and that tutorial was the second result. This is just in case you're interested in how I found that answer.

Comment: Thank you, I used the tutorial, however, upon running I got a strange App Delegate crash so I have not tested it yet. @JoshuaKaden

Answer (score 0):

If the task is to add an image, you should use something like this in cellForItemAtIndexPath:

```
let myCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("MyCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
myCell.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
let imageView = UIImageView(frame: cell.contentView.frame)
cell.contentView.addSubview(imageView)
imageView.image = //Here you should get right UIImage like ImageStore().imageForKey("YOUR_KEY")
return myCell
```

Or you can use custom UICollectionViewCell subclass as Joshua Kaden wrote.

Comment: I'd check for the presence of the image view before adding it; otherwise you might wind up adding image view on top of image view (since the cells are potentially reused).